# how to 'skip' a word when using linguex glosses

Tags: spacing, linguistics, linguex, cgloss4e

I am using the `linguex` package for my glosses. This package allows you to write a sentence in a language, and add glosses aligned with the original example right above it. For example:

```
\exg. \%*Wen$_i$ liebt$_k$ seine$_i$ Mutter t$_i$ t$_k$?\\
         Whom  loves  his   mother\\
        ‘Who does his mother love?’
```

[image]

Apparently there must be a direct correspondence between the words on the first and second line. However, what I need to do is just to 'skip' a word of the first line. In the example below, I need to skip *t*:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\renewcommand{\firstrefdash}{} 

\begin{document}

 \exg. Chi pensi t verrà alla festa?
       Who think.2g come.FUT.3sg a=D party
       `Who do you think will come to the party?'

 \end{document}
```

Does anyone know how I can do that?

Comment: Could you please make the last snippet into a full (but minimal) example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`?

Comment: Sorry, it's such a simple question, I didn't think an MWE was necessary! Added now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an empty group:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{linguex}
\renewcommand{\firstrefdash}{}

\begin{document}

\exg. Chi pensi t verrà alla festa? \\
      Who think.2g come.FUT.3sg a=D party \\
      `Who do you think will come to the party?'

\exg. Chi pensi t verrà alla festa? \\
      Who think.2g {} come.FUT.3sg a=D party \\
      `Who do you think will come to the party?'

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying! It says there is an error: `Argument of \UTFviii@three@octets has an extra }.`

Comment: I tried to remove the command `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, and it works now! Thanks for the suggestion!